# TFS 2017 Builds and SpecFlow integration

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, specflow

I am trying to run SpecFlow tests as part of a TFS Build. Is there a way i can set it up without the SpecFlow+ runner. What are the advantages of using SpecFlow+ runner?

Anyone has experience setting these up?

Answer (score 2):

> **SpecFlow+ runner**
>
> Smarter integration test runner for SpecFlow
>
> SpecFlow+ Runner is a dedicated **test execution engine** providing better
>   reporting, faster (parallel) test execution and better VS/TFS
>   integration

Highly recommend  to use specflow+ runner to run specflow tests via TFS.

To configure your build process in TFS 2017 to execute tests using SpecFlow+ Runner:

1. Open TFS and switch to your build definition.
2. Click on **Add build step** to add a new step to the build definition.
   Click on **Test** in the list of categories and click on **Add** next to
   "Visual Studio Test".
3. Configure the build step as follows:

   Enter the path to your **Test Assembly**

   If you are using both MSTest and SpecFlow+ Runner, enter
   the path to NuGet package folder in the **Path to Custom Test Adapters**
   field. If you do not enter the path here, only your MSTest tests
   will be executed as TFS cannot find the SpecFlow+Runner test
   adapter.

   Enter the name of your .srprofile file in the **Run Settings File**
   field if the name is not `TFS.srprofile` or `default.srprofile` (see
   above).
4. Save your changes.

More details please refer this tutorial: [SpecFlow+ And Build Servers](http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-and-Build-Servers/)